# SSRS Sorting option showing beginning of the column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have created a matrix report in SSRS and added a sort option to the first column. when I deployed in the report server, then sort option showing at the beginning of the column.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen this before but I don't use the interactive sort much to be honest. Have you tried other browsers? Does the same happen in other reports? Does it look OK in Visual studio (or Report Builder if that's what you used to design the report)

Comment: @AlanSchofield, this issue is only in the browser. In Visual studio, it is showing correctly

Comment: Have you tried different browsers, different reports?